# Edit rejected due to "change of original meaning", but I disagree

Tags: discussion

I tidied up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650057/2047122) in a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5076856).  I described the changes in my edit title:

- Added method signature, fixed typo "tableColoumn" -> tableColumn, added a default value for heightOfRow, changed some tabs into spaces to improve indentation, added some comments

My edit has been rejected, as it "changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost".  But I disagree: I was careful to maintain the original meaning.  I just wanted to tidy up the answer by fixing the various formatting mistakes and showing the surrounding method context, to make the answer more useful to others.

Perhaps the reviewers thought that the method signature I've introduced changes the meaning.  But this method is the only way I'm aware of to set a different height for each table row on OS X, and this method is referred to implicitly at the end of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3214834/2047122) ("... referencing it when the row height delegate method is called").  I think an answer that gives the method signature would improve the page and make it a bit easier to find through searching.

Comment: fixing the naming of `tableColumn` was ok, but where you ran into trouble is when you started adding to the code.  Commenting with your suggestions to improve the code (and letting the author do the changes), or leaving your own answer, is considered more acceptable to the community

Comment: Thanks - I'll submit my edited version as another answer, then, describing it as based on the original, and leave a comment on the original.  A shame as it clutters the page, though.  Ah well.  But, also... I'm already planning on submitting another answer which uses a substantially different implementation.  I guess submitting two answers is OK?

Comment: If the edit gets approved and later receives downvotes, the original author will suffer the consequences ( rep loss, ban etc), author won't even know that the answer was modified by you, that is why you should post your own answer if you have such significant changes. An answer is very closely related to an author's profile on SO.

Comment: People are reluctant to approve suggested edits that make non-trivial changes (yet simultaneously complain about suggested edits that make only trivial changes). The problem is magnified by 10 if you touch code. It is a largely insoluble problem. The only real solution is to earn the requisite reputation to give you full editing privileges. Then you can improve answers according to your best judgment to the benefit of all. Payeli's concern is not a valid one; there's a "rollback" button for edits that truly subvert the author's original intent, and there is a full tracked history of edits.

Comment: @CodyGray that's a bit of a slippery slope.  Were it valid, almost any edit could be justified by "someone will just roll it back if it's bad."  I'd rather people think a little more about their edits than that.